# How do I pull singe cell RNA sequencing data from GEO database?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, ncbi

I am new to R and computational biology. I am trying to look through a published data set to check for gene expression for my own project. I am having trouble finding materials to teach me how to analyze single cell RNA sequencing data on R from the GEO NCBI database.

This is the data that I am trying to access https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE138651

I would appreciate any directions or suggestions for tutorials.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Diana! I think this question in its current form will likely be closed. If you are asking how to do the analysis, SO is not a site for tutorials in general much less context-specific topics such as RNA sequencing analysis; you are expected to do that research elsewhere and come to SO with implementation problems with your data-reading or existing code.

Comment: Added to @r2evans cooments, I think you can go to Bioinformatics community https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/, maybe there is some questions treating similar issues. Check also BioStar https://www.biostars.org/

Comment: oh great, I didn't know that! thank you for the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [BioConductor *`GEOquery`* package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GEOquery.html).

Install using

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
```

More information on how to use this package and read in data from GEO can be found in the [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.html)